# Calculating if CGPoint is on a line segment?

Tags: ios, swift, geometry

I'm looking for a way to calculate if a CGPoint is on a line segment. Are there any built-in methods in Swift or any of Apple's libraries?

I don't mind converting to a different type as long as it is part of Apple's code (e.g. similar to how [instead of performing complex calculations on double4x4 matrix, you can convert it to an SCNNode](https://medium.com/@norling.samuel/arkit-dont-read-the-transform-1ab771f49e64)).

---

I quickly came up with brute force solution, but it's neither elegant, nor accurate (given floating point comparisons everywhere):

```
extension CGPoint {
  func isOnLineSegment(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    func value(_ value: CGFloat, isBetween one: CGFloat, and two: CGFloat) -> Bool {
      let a = [one, two].sorted()
      return a[0] <= value && value <= a[1]
    }

    let slope = (end.y - start.y) / (end.x - start.x)
    if slope.isInfinite {
      let isOnLine = x.isNearlyEqual(to: start.x)
      let isWithinYValues = value(y, isBetween: start.y, and: end.y)
      return isOnLine && isWithinYValues
    }

    let isOnLine = y.isNearlyEqual(to: slope * (x - start.x) + start.y) // y = m * (x - x1) + y1
    let isWithinXValues = value(x, isBetween: start.x, and: end.x)

    return isOnLine && isWithinXValues
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar problem recently — I first [converted the line into a thin rectangle](https://github.com/aheze/AccessibleReality/blob/e73cfb433a70e6060feabfdbe178fa87103a2a23/Source/PlaygroundBook/Modules/BookCore.playgroundmodule/Sources/Main/AR/MainVC%2BCheckOverlap.swift#L95). Then, I [checked if the rectangle bezier contained the point](https://github.com/aheze/AccessibleReality/blob/e73cfb433a70e6060feabfdbe178fa87103a2a23/Submission/AndrewZ-AccessibleReality/Accessible%20Reality.playgroundbook/Contents/Modules/BookCore.playgroundmodule/Sources/Main/AR/MainVC%2BLineOverlap.swift#L15).

Comment: It's even more complex than your solution, but it has the advantage of allowing some error - you can specify how far away the point can be from the line

Comment: @aheze: I would always try *not* to compute/use the slope of a line. Even if you capture the case of a vertical line (where the denominator becomes zero) you'll probably lose precision for “almost vertical” lines due to the large numbers. – In https://github.com/aheze/AccessibleReality/blob/e73cfb433a70e6060feabfdbe178fa87103a2a23/Source/PlaygroundBook/Modules/BookCore.playgroundmodule/Sources/Main/AR/MainVC%2BCheckOverlap.swift#L95 you can use `atan2` as an alternative which does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: @MartinR: in fact you don't need the angle, only rotation coefficients, so the recourse to the arc tangent is superfluous/not welcome.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is correct. I just wanted to draw attention to the “danger” of calculating with slopes.

Comment: @MartinR good point about the 0 denominator. How come `atan2` will work though? Btw congrats on 500k and nice profile pic!

Comment: @aheze: [`atan2(y, x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) takes two arguments and computes the angle depending on the sign and magnitude of the coordinates. This can always be done in a way that the denominator does not become too small. Another advantage of `atan2` is that it works correctly for all arguments between -π and π.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to transform the whole configuration such that the start point of the segment is transformed to the origin, and the end point is transformed to the point (1, 0). This can be done with a `CGAffineTransformation`. The problem then reduces to determining if the given point is on the line segment between (0, 0) and (1,0). Here is a possible implementation:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func isOnLineSegment(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        // Transformation which maps (0,0) to start and (1, 0) to end:
        let t = CGAffineTransform(a: end.x - start.x, b: end.y - start.y,
                                  c: start.y - end.y, d: end.x - start.x,
                                  tx: start.x, ty: start.y)
        // Apply the inverse transformation to our point:
        let q = self.applying(t.inverted())
        // Check (with some tolerance) if q is on the segment from (0, 0) to (1, 0):
        let eps = CGFloat.ulpOfOne.squareRoot()
        return q.x > -eps && q.x < 1.0 + eps && q.y.magnitude < eps 
    }
}
```

As tolerance I chose the square root of [`.ulpOfOne`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/3017999-ulpofone) (as suggested [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0259-approximately-equal.md)), but you can adjust it to your needs.

Another approach is to use the fact that a point P is on the line segment from P1 to P2 exactly if

```
| P - P1 | + | P - P2 | = | P1 - P2 |
```

where `| . |` denotes the (Euclidean) distance:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to p: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return hypot(p.x - self.x, p.y - self.y)
    }
    func isOnLineSegment(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        let eps = CGFloat.ulpOfOne.squareRoot()
        return self.distance(to: start) + self.distance(to: end) <= start.distance(to: end) + eps
    }
}
```

Comment: With the second approach, if you accept equality to a tolerance, the locus of the points "on" the segment is the interior of an ellipse with foci at the endpoints.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You are right, I had also noticed that in my tests. I will probably delete that part. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I didn't say that this is bad !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It might be unexpected if the tolerance is greater in the middle of the line than at the endpoints.

Comment: No more unexpected, as it it mentioned in the comments to your post ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you fear floating-point inaccuracies, you'd better compute the distance to the line segment and check if it falls under a tolerance. (I will not expand on how to select this tolerance.)

An efficient computation scheme is as follows, using complex numbers (I use them for convenience, but there are equivalent vector forms, or just scalar expressions):

- translate one of the endpoints to the origin (now the segment is `0` to `P1-P0` and the tested point is `Q-P0`);
- rotate to make the segment horizontal; for this, you multiply by (`R:= (P1-P0)*/|P1-P0|`, where `*` denotes the complex conjugate.
- now the real part of `(Q-P0).R` tells you if the point projects to the segment (when `0≤Im≤|P1-P0|`).

  - if yes, the imaginary part is the distance to the segment;
  - if no, compute the distance to the nearest endpoint (you know which by looking at the above real part).

The picture illustrates the three different cases to get the distance to the segment (transformed points).

[image]

---

**Technical notes:**

1. Depending on your needs, you can adopt different strategies for the handling of the endpoints:

- a point past the endpoint can be considered outside the segment;
- a point past the endpoint *horizontally* by more than the tolerance can be considered outside the segment;
- a point past the endpoint *obliquely* by more than the tolerance can be considered outside the segment.

These options correspond to acceptance domains with respective shapes being tight rectangle, larger rectangle and rounded rectangle.

2. This method preserves scale, making the tolerance an absolute distance criterion.

Comment: Just mentioning that translating one point to the origin and rotating the other point to the positive x-axis is exactly what the CGAffineTransform in my suggested code does :)

Comment: @MartinR: that's quite right. You normalize the segment length to be unit, meaning that the tolerance is influenced by the initial segment length. The OP should check if this is a desirable property or not.

Comment: Yes, I had thought about that. I chose this approach because floating point inaccuracies are usually proportional to the magnitude of the involved numbers.

Comment: @MartinR: this is why I said "I will not expand on how to select this tolerance", the topic is complex.